# Regex: Replace last segment of url

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I try to figure out the correct regex to replace the last segment of an url with a modified version of that very last segment. (I know that there are similar threads out there, but none seemed to help...)

Example:

```
https://www.test.com/one/two/three/mypost/
--->
one/two/three?id=mypost


https://www.test.com/one/mypost/
--->
one?id=mypost
```

Now I am stuck here:
https://regex101.com/r/9GqYaU/1

I can get the last segment in capturing group 2 but how would I replace it?
I think I will have to something like this:

```
  const url = 'https://www.test.com/one/two/three/mypost/'
  const regex = /(http[s]?:\/\/)([^\/]+\/)*(?=\/$|$)/
  const path = url.replace(regex, `${myUrlWithoutTheLastSegmentAnd WithoutHTTPS}?id=$2`)
  return path
```

But I have no idea how to get the url without the last segment. I have currently only access to the whole string or group 1 (which is useless in this case) and then group 2, but not the string without group 2.

I would be very glad for any help here. Sometimes I just lack the knowledge of what is possible with regex and how to achieve it.

Thank you in advance.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the URL class to extract the pathname and `substring` to remove the first '/'.

Then, you could put the last part of the pathname in a group and use it as a reference `$1` for the replacement.

```js
const url = new URL('https://www.test.com/one/two/three/mypost/').pathname.substring(1)

console.log(url.replace(/\/([^/]*)\/$/, '?id=$1'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across your question yesterday and agree with going down the route of parsing the URL. Once you get there you could even use JavaScript array methods which I prefer to string methods like:

```
pathname.split("/").filter(p => p.length).pop()
```

This would separate each folder, ignore any with no length (i.e. handle a trailing slash) and return the last one (`mypost`).

Anyway, I am also learning regex so sometimes when I find a question like this I just try to find the answer anyway as the best way of learning is doing. It took 24 hours  I came up with this:

```
/(https?:\/\/).+?([a-z-]*)\/?$/gm
```

`(https?:\/\/)` you know what this does. Small correction, you don't need the square brackets. Question mark matches 0 or 1 of the preceding character. As we're only matching `s` this just works. If you wanted to match s or z you would use `[sz]?`. I think.

`.+?` this is the cool one I think I will use in future now I found it. The question mark here has a different meaning - it makes `.+` (which means one or more of any character) non-greedy. That means it stops applying once it reaches the next rule. Which is...

`([a-z-]*)` any number of letters or a hyphen. You should maybe change this to include numbers and upper case.

`\/?` Optional slash

`$` all this must apply at the end of the string.

Here is a demo
https://regex101.com/r/mQNkIS/1

Comment: 24h. haha. Nice. Thanks a lot for your elaborate answer! I think this will help me somewhere in my future when I stumble across regex the next time ;).